# How to successfully call AJAX to update collection_select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

The idea is that the `challenges` in `collection_select` should change based upon who the user is in `select`.

How can we fix the `<script>` so that just the user's challenges are listed?

**duels/_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, User.order(:name).map { |user| [user.full_name, user.id] }, include_blank: true, id: "change-challenge-options" %>

  will

<%= render partial: 'user_challenges', locals: { challenges: Challenge.order(:created_at) } %>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     # $( "#change-challenge-options" ).change(function() { // Doesn't fire if I put this line back in
      console.log("Fired!"); # Is firing
      $.ajax({
        url: '<%= user_challenges_path %>',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {name: $('#change-challenge-options').prop('value')},
       success:function(result)
       {
        alert('Successfully called');
       },
       error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);} # But error is raising
      })
     # })
    })
</script>
```

**duels/_user_challenges.html.erb**

```
<div id="dropdown-no-2">
  <%= collection_select(:dueler, :challenge_id, challenges, :id, :full_challenge, include_blank: true) %>
</div>
```

**duels/user_challenges.js.erb**

```
$("#dropdown-no-2").html('<%=j render :partial => "user_challenges", locals: {challenges: @challenges} %>');
```

**duels_controller**

```
def user_challenges # Not sure if I should put @user & @challenges here or under def new
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
end

def new
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @challenges = @user.challenges.order(:created_at)
  @duel = Duel.new
  @duel.duelers << Dueler.new(user_id: current_user.id, user_name: current_user.name, user_last_name: current_user.last_name)
respond_with(@duel)
end
```

Comment: What values does `@challenges` in `duels/user_challenges.js.erb` holds?

Comment: @Pavan I updated question.

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: Also try changing `name: $('#change-challenge-options').prop('value')` to `name: $("#change-challenge-options option:selected").text()`

Comment: And also you are sending ***name*** not ***id***. So change `@user = User.find(params[:id])` to `@user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])`

Comment: @Pavan the popup alert says `Exception:[object Object]`. You make great points. I updated my code with your suggestions, but nothing changed. How would you write the `<script>`? How would you start the code chunk, i.e. with `$(document).ready(function()` and/or `$( "#change-challenge-options" ).change(function()`

Comment: Ah! There it is!. You should put `$('#change-challenge-options').change(function() {` under the `$(document).ready(function(){`. And the entire Ajax code should come under the `$('#change-challenge-options').change(function() {`

Comment: @Pavan that's what I had though, sorry it wasn't clear in the question. I had commented it out. I said if I use `$('#change-challenge-options').change(function() ` then `console.log("Fired!");` doesn't fire and neither does the AJAX :/